# how do i open/render .bmp images in vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, bmp

I'm using C to make a few filters that will get applied on .bmp files. I am using vscode and I need to somehow render the images to test if my algorithm works. Right now vscode is having trouble opening it and saying this: [image: vscode not rendering .bmp file]

Is there a sort of extension or anything I can enable to view these files?

UPDATE:
VSCode seems to have solved the issue by itself. My .bmp files open without any problems. No extensions downloaded nor any changes made to my code.

Comment: openCV has a function to show images, or convert the image to a PNG or JPEG

Comment: VSCode is ok with unedited versions of the image. They can be seen perfectly fine when i don't apply my algorithm to them. However, after I apply the filter to them, the image is unable to be viewed. I Changed it to other formats and they don't work either.

Comment: have you tried to open the image with `Paint` or `gimp`? Open the image in Notepad++ to see what it is like, or the Hex-editor of VSC

Comment: I used the hexdump extension on vscode and it seems the header file has been changed. There is a slight difference, in that the header file of the edited image is one off the header file of the new image. I think this may be the issue? I'll try fixing this and seeing what happens.